# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-1m’

Tags: c, gcc

When I run my C code that includes

```
#include <math.h>
```

and later down in a for loop

```
distance[i] = (float) pow((float) pow(X1[i] - xpos[i],2)+(float) pow(X2[i] - ypos[i],2),0.5);
```

and attempting to compile with

```
gcc test.c -o test -1m
```

I get the error

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-1m’
```

Do I need to download something onto my computer or something?

When I have a different maths expression in the for loop (one that doesn't need math.h) my code compiles and run perfectly.

Comment: use `sqrt(x) instead of `pow(x, 0.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's supposed to be `-lm` with a lowercase L for "library". You're linking the math library.